# jQuery fadeOut pairs of links

Tags: jquery

I'm making a word game to help me learn German. I have 2 arrays, one for German and the other for English. I'm then displaying all of the words onto an HTML page as links with a class of "language" and "position" which is a number with a space inbetween. What I would like is the German and the English words to fadeOut when they're paired together. This is the click event I have so far:

```
function setup()
{
    var check = { language: undefined, position: null };

    $("a").on("click", function()
    {
        var attributes = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");

        if (attributes[0] == "german") {
            if (check["language"] == "german") {
                alert("German word already clicked!");
                check["language"] = undefined;
                check["position"] = null;
                return;
            }

            if (check["language"] == "english") {
                if (check["position"] == attributes[1]) {
                    $(this).fadeOut(800);
                }
            }

            check["language"] = attributes[0];
            check["position"] = attributes[1];
        }

        if (attributes[0] == "english") {
            if (check["language"] == "english") {
                alert("English word already clicked!");
                check["language"] = undefined;
                check["position"] = null;
                return;
            }

            if (check["language"] == "german") {
                if (check["position"] == attributes[1]) {
                    $(this).fadeOut(800);
                }
            }

            check["language"] = attributes[0];
            check["position"] = attributes[1];
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT:

```
function wordlist(obj)
{
    for (i = 0; i < obj["wordlist"].length; i ++) {
        $("#main .span12").append("<a href=\"#\" class=\"" + obj["language"] + " " + i + "\">" + obj["wordlist"][i] + "</a><br/>");
    }
}
```

FULL DISCLOSURE:

I've finished with my word game and so I've decided to give back to the community by submitting my finalized version so others can use. The game also supports randomized wordlists wich are then merged together. Please comment if you think you can improve the code.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    (function training()
    {
        Array.prototype.shuffle = function()
        {
            var i = this.length, j, temp;
            if (i == 0) return this;

            while (--i) {
                j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
                temp = this[i];
                this[i] = this[j];
                this[j] = temp;
            }
            return this;
        }

        var german =
        {
            language: "german",
            wordlist:
            [
                "der Zusammenhang",
                "der Wirt",
                "der Kaufmann",
                "das Gesetz",
                "(sich) klammern (an)",
                "der Lastwagen",
                "die Akte",
                "das Gericht",
                "zahlen",
                "zählen (bis, auf)"
            ]
        },
        english =
        {
            language: "english",
            wordlist:
            [
                "connection",
                "landlord",
                "dealer",
                "law",
                "to attach (to)",
                "truck",
                "file",
                "dish",
                "to pay",
                "to count (to, on)"
            ]
        };

        function generate(obj)
        {
            var array = [];

            for (i = 0; i < obj["wordlist"].length; i ++) {
                array.push("<a href=\"#\" class=\"" + obj["language"] + " " + i + "\">" + obj["wordlist"][i] + "</a><br/>");
            }
            return array;
        }

        var german = generate(german);
        var english = generate(english);

        var wordlist = german.concat(english);
        wordlist.shuffle();

        $("#main .span12").append(wordlist);

        (function setup()
        {
            var check = { language: undefined, position: null };

            $("a").on("click", function()
            {
                var attributes = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");

                if (attributes[0] == "german") {
                    if (check["language"] == "german") {
                        alert("    German word clicked!\nPlease click an English word.");
                        check["language"] = undefined;
                        check["position"] = null;
                        return;
                    }

                    if (check["language"] == "english") {
                        if (check["position"] == attributes[1]) {
                            $("." + attributes[1]).fadeOut(800);
                            $("." + attributes[1]).remove();
                        }
                    }

                    check["language"] = attributes[0];
                    check["position"] = attributes[1];
                }

                if (attributes[0] == "english") {
                    if (check["language"] == "english") {
                        alert("      English word clicked!\nPlease click a German word.");
                        check["language"] = undefined;
                        check["position"] = null;
                        return;
                    }

                    if (check["language"] == "german") {
                        if (check["position"] == attributes[1]) {
                            $("." + attributes[1]).fadeOut(800);
                            $("." + attributes[1]).remove();
                        }
                    }

                    check["language"] = attributes[0];
                    check["position"] = attributes[1];
                }
            });

            (function loop()
            {
                var timer = setTimeout(loop, 1000);
                var links = $("a");

                if (links.length == 0) {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    alert("Well done!");
                    return;
                }
            })();
        })();
    })();
});
```

Comment: What you exactly want? Do you want to fadeOut both <a> tag?

Comment: Tell me your problem some more specific so that I can help you.

Comment: @Shukla Yes, I would like both tags to fade out. Thank you

Comment: Can you write your html? only part of <a> will need so just write that part please. I think you just need to add id or class and your problem will be solved.

Comment: @Shukla All of the links are generated using JavaScript.

Comment: Can you just tell me what is obj["language"]?

Comment: I have a wordlist function which is being passed an object. The obj is an object which contains a variable called "language" and is being used to populate the link class with the language and an array which contains all of the words. For example I would use it like this: wordlist(german) or wordlist(english).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replce

```
$(this).fadeOut(800);
```

to

```
$("."+attributes[1]).fadeOut(800); 
OR
$("."+check["position"]).fadeOut(800);
```

Comment: @ShuklaJay check your answer is differ from mine. its surly works.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
function setup()
{
var check = { language: undefined, position: null };
$("a").on("click", function()
{
    var attributes = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");

    if (attributes[0] == "german") {
        if (check["language"] == "german") {
            alert("German word already clicked!");
            check["language"] = undefined;
            check["position"] = null;
            return;
        }

        if (check["language"] == "english") {
                $("a." + check["language"]).fadeOut(800);
                $("a").not("a." + check["language"]).fadeIn(800);
        }

        check["language"] = attributes[0];
        check["position"] = attributes[1];
    }

    if (attributes[0] == "english") {
        if (check["language"] == "english") {
            alert("English word already clicked!");
            check["language"] = undefined;
            check["position"] = null;
            return;
        }

        if (check["language"] == "german") {
                $("a." + check["language"]).fadeOut(800);
                $("a").not("a." + check["language"]).fadeIn(800);
        }

        check["language"] = attributes[0];
        check["position"] = attributes[1];
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Afraid not. When I first click a German word and then an English one both English words fade out and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I think it's very similar to Dh's answer.